Is Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered important?
I am trying to train a machine learning model and use tensorflow, cuda, and cuDNN to speed up the training. I keep getting errorr/warnings though. Are they anything to be concerned about. ie. Is my GPU properly being used for training my machine learning model?
Log messages
2024-12-26 21:12:28.304061: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:153] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2024-12-26 21:12:28.315852: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:477] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
E0000 00:00:1735265548.330579  628897 cuda_dnn.cc:8310] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
E0000 00:00:1735265548.333768  628897 cuda_blas.cc:1418] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2024-12-26 21:12:28.343150: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
GPU(s) detected and memory limited to 4GB: 1
libEGL warning: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)

libEGL warning: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)

libEGL warning: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)

libEGL warning: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)

libEGL warning: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)

libEGL warning: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)

Processing videos in /mnt/c/Users/Rohit/Desktop/Science Fair 2024-2025/data/Correct sequence:   0%|                                                                                       | 0/50 [00:00<?, ?it/s]INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
W0000 00:00:1735265550.005106  628955 inference_feedback_manager.cc:114] Feedback manager requires a model with a single signature inference. Disabling support for feedback tensors.
W0000 00:00:1735265550.033803  628955 inference_feedback_manager.cc:114] Feedback manager requires a model with a single signature inference. Disabling support for feedback tensors.
W0000 00:00:1735265550.057371  628956 landmark_projection_calculator.cc:186] Using NORM_RECT without IMAGE_DIMENSIONS is only supported for the square ROI. Provide IMAGE_DIMENSIONS or use PROJECTION_MATRIX.
Processing videos in /mnt/c/Users/Rohit/Desktop/Science Fair 2024-2025/data/Correct sequence: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 50/50 [01:15<00:00,  1.50s/it]
Processing videos in /mnt/c/Users/Rohit/Desktop/Science Fair 2024-2025/data/Wrong sequence: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 50/50 [01:44<00:00,  2.10s/it]
starting gridSearch
Fitting 3 folds for each of 512 candidates, totalling 1536 fits
[CV 1/3; 1/512] START batch_size=16, dense_units=128, dropoutRate_1=0.3, epochs=10, filters_1=32, filters_2=64, kernel_size_1=3, kernel_size_2=3, optimizer=adam
I0000 00:00:1735265732.230426  628897 gpu_device.cc:2022] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 4096 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
Epoch 1/10
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
I0000 00:00:1735265733.491319  630700 service.cc:148] XLA service 0x7fa86800a800 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
I0000 00:00:1735265733.491354  630700 service.cc:156]   StreamExecutor device (0): NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti, Compute Capability 8.6
2024-12-26 21:15:33.508585: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tensorflow/utils/dump_mlir_util.cc:268] disabling MLIR crash reproducer, set env var `MLIR_CRASH_REPRODUCER_DIRECTORY` to enable.
I0000 00:00:1735265733.614116  630700 cuda_dnn.cc:529] Loaded cuDNN version 90300
I0000 00:00:1735265734.909895  630700 device_compiler.h:188] Compiled cluster using XLA!  This line is logged at most once for the lifetime of the process.
4/4 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3s 426ms/step - accuracy: 0.4600 - loss: 1.0011
Epoch 2/10
4/4 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 7ms/step - accuracy: 0.6064 - loss: 0.6028
Epoch 3/10
4/4 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 7ms/step - accuracy: 0.5376 - loss: 0.7551
Epoch 4/10
4/4 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 6ms/step - accuracy: 0.6845 - loss: 0.6672
Epoch 5/10
4/4 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 8ms/step - accuracy: 0.5569 - loss: 0.7145
Epoch 6/10
4/4 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 8ms/step - accuracy: 0.6282 - loss: 0.6590
Epoch 7/10
4/4 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 10ms/step - accuracy: 0.6733 - loss: 0.6427
Epoch 8/10
4/4 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 9ms/step - accuracy: 0.6712 - loss: 0.6095
Epoch 9/10
4/4 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 8ms/step - accuracy: 0.5936 - loss: 0.6401
Epoch 10/10
4/4 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 6ms/step - accuracy: 0.6642 - loss: 0.6658
[CV 1/3; 1/512] END batch_size=16, dense_units=128, dropoutRate_1=0.3, epochs=10, filters_1=32, filters_2=64, kernel_size_1=3, kernel_size_2=3, optimizer=adam; accuracy: (test=nan) f1: (test=nan) precision: (test=nan) recall: (test=nan) total time=   4.5s


Additionally when running the code overnight, I got this error message:
joblib.externals.loky.process_executor.TerminatedWorkerError: A worker process managed by the executor was unexpectedly terminated. This could be caused by a segmentation fault while calling the function or by an excessive memory usage causing the Operating System to kill the worker.
The exit codes of the workers are {SIGKILL(-9)}
Code
import os
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, ParameterGrid
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm
from joblib import dump
from keras import Input
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score, roc_auc_score, make_scorer, confusion_matrix


# ===== ENVIRONMENT SETUP =====
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
os.environ['TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS'] = '0'
tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')

gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
    try:
        for gpu in gpus:
            tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration(
                gpu,
                [tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=4096)]  # 4GB limit
            )
        print(f"GPU(s) detected and memory limited to 4GB: {len(gpus)}")
    except RuntimeError as e:
        print(f"GPU configuration error: {e}")
else:
    print("No GPU detected. Using CPU.")

# ===== PATH CONFIGURATION =====
basePath = "/mnt/c/Users/Rohit/Desktop/Science Fair 2024-2025/data"
correctPath = os.path.join(basePath, "Correct sequence")
wrongPath = os.path.join(basePath, "Wrong sequence")
fixedFrameCount = 100

# ===== MEDIAPIPE SETUP =====
mpPose = mp.solutions.pose
pose = mpPose.Pose(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5)

# ===== DATA PROCESSING FUNCTIONS =====
def extractPoseLandmarks(videoPath):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoPath)
    landmarksData = []

    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break

        frameRgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        results = pose.process(frameRgb)

        if results.pose_landmarks:
            landmarks = [
                [lm.x, lm.y, lm.z, lm.visibility] for lm in results.pose_landmarks.landmark
            ]
            landmarksData.append(np.array(landmarks).flatten())

    cap.release()
    return np.array(landmarksData)

def padOrTruncate(sequence, fixedLength):
    if len(sequence) > fixedLength:
        return sequence[:fixedLength]
    padding = np.zeros((fixedLength - len(sequence), sequence.shape[1]), dtype=sequence.dtype)
    return np.vstack((sequence, padding))

def labelVideos(videoFolder, label):
    videoData, labels = [], []
    for videoFile in tqdm(os.listdir(videoFolder), desc=f"Processing videos in {videoFolder}"):
        if videoFile.lower().endswith((".mp4", ".avi", ".mov")):
            videoPath = os.path.join(videoFolder, videoFile)
            landmarks = extractPoseLandmarks(videoPath)
            if landmarks.shape[0] > 0:
                paddedLandmarks = padOrTruncate(landmarks, fixedFrameCount)
                videoData.append(paddedLandmarks)
                labels.append(label)
    return np.array(videoData), np.array(labels)

# ===== DATA LOADING =====
correctData, correctLabels = labelVideos(correctPath, label=1)
wrongData, wrongLabels = labelVideos(wrongPath, label=0)

X = np.concatenate((correctData, wrongData), axis=0)
y = np.concatenate((correctLabels, wrongLabels), axis=0)

# Reshape for CNN input
num_features_per_landmark = X.shape[2]
X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], fixedFrameCount, num_features_per_landmark)

# Split dataset
trainSize = int(0.8 * len(X))
XTrain, XTest = X[:trainSize], X[trainSize:]
yTrain, yTest = y[:trainSize], y[trainSize:]

# ===== CNN MODEL FUNCTION =====
def createModel(optimizer='adam', filters_1=32, kernel_size_1=3, dropoutRate_1=0.3,
                filters_2=64, kernel_size_2=3, dense_units=128):
    model = models.Sequential()

    # First Convolutional Layer
    model.add(Input(shape=(fixedFrameCount, num_features_per_landmark)))  # Define input shape here
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(
        filters=filters_1,
        kernel_size=kernel_size_1,
        activation='relu'
    ))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(dropoutRate_1))

    # Second Convolutional Layer
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(
        filters=filters_2,
        kernel_size=kernel_size_2,
        activation='relu'
    ))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))

    # Flatten and Fully Connected Layers
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(dense_units, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    # Compile Model
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

# Wrap the model for GridSearchCV
model = KerasClassifier(
    model=createModel,
    optimizer='adam',
    filters_1=32,
    kernel_size_1=3,
    dropoutRate_1=0.3,
    filters_2=64,
    kernel_size_2=3,
    dense_units=128,
    batch_size=16,
    epochs=10,
    verbose=0
)


# ===== GRIDSEARCH SETUP =====
paramGrid = {
    'optimizer': ['adam', 'sgd'],
    'filters_1': [32, 64],
    'kernel_size_1': [3, 5],
    'dropoutRate_1': [0.3, 0.5],
    'filters_2': [64, 128],
    'kernel_size_2': [3, 5],
    'dense_units': [128, 256],
    'batch_size': [16, 32],
    'epochs': [10, 20]
}

# Count total parameter combinations
total_combinations = len(list(ParameterGrid(paramGrid)))

# Progress bar setup
# progress_bar = tqdm(total=total_combinations, desc="GridSearch Progress")


scoring_metrics = {
    'accuracy': 'accuracy',
    'precision': 'precision',
    'recall': 'recall',
    'f1': 'f1'
}

input("starting gridSearch")
# Set up GridSearchCV
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=paramGrid, cv=3, verbose=100, n_jobs=1, scoring=scoring_metrics, refit='accuracy')
gridResult = grid.fit(XTrain, yTrain, verbose = True)

# ===== EVALUATE BEST MODEL =====

bestParams = gridResult.best_params_
bestModel = gridResult.best_estimator_

# Predict using the best estimator
yPred = bestModel.predict(XTest)

# Evaluate the model using different scoring metrics
accuracy = accuracy_score(yTest, yPred)
precision = precision_score(yTest, yPred)
recall = recall_score(yTest, yPred)
f1 = f1_score(yTest, yPred)

print(f"Best Parameters: {bestParams}")
print(f"Accuracy on test set: {accuracy}")
print(f"Precision on test set: {precision}")
print(f"Recall on test set: {recall}")
print(f"F1-score on test set: {f1}")

dump(bestModel, "bestModel.joblib")
test_loss, test_acc = bestModel.model.evaluate(XTest, yTest)
print(f"Test Accuracy: {test_acc * 100:.2f}%")

# ===== PLOT BEST MODEL PERFORMANCE =====
history = bestModel.fit(XTrain, yTrain, epochs=gridResult.best_params_['epochs'], batch_size=gridResult.best_params_['batch_size'], validation_data=(XTest, yTest))

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

# Plot training & validation accuracy values
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.title('Model Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.legend()

# Plot training & validation loss values
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='Validation Loss')
plt.title('Model Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

I tried reinstalling everything in a new conda environment. Here is the packages I have
Package                      Version
---------------------------- -----------
absl-py                      2.1.0
astunparse                   1.6.3
attrs                        24.3.0
certifi                      2024.12.14
cffi                         1.17.1
charset-normalizer           3.4.1
contourpy                    1.3.0
cycler                       0.12.1
flatbuffers                  24.12.23
fonttools                    4.55.3
gast                         0.6.0
google-pasta                 0.2.0
grpcio                       1.68.1
h5py                         3.12.1
idna                         3.10
importlib_metadata           8.5.0
importlib_resources          6.4.5
jax                          0.4.30
jaxlib                       0.4.30
joblib                       1.4.2
keras                        3.7.0
keras-tuner                  1.4.7
kiwisolver                   1.4.7
kt-legacy                    1.0.5
libclang                     18.1.1
Markdown                     3.7
markdown-it-py               3.0.0
MarkupSafe                   3.0.2
matplotlib                   3.9.4
mdurl                        0.1.2
mediapipe                    0.10.20
ml-dtypes                    0.4.1
namex                        0.0.8
numpy                        1.26.4
nvidia-cublas-cu12           12.5.3.2
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12       12.5.82
nvidia-cuda-nvcc-cu12        12.5.82
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12       12.5.82
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12     12.5.82
nvidia-cudnn-cu12            9.3.0.75
nvidia-cufft-cu12            11.2.3.61
nvidia-curand-cu12           10.3.6.82
nvidia-cusolver-cu12         11.6.3.83
nvidia-cusparse-cu12         12.5.1.3
nvidia-nccl-cu12             2.21.5
nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12        12.5.82
opencv-contrib-python        4.10.0.84
opencv-python-headless       4.10.0.84
opt_einsum                   3.4.0
optree                       0.13.1
packaging                    24.2
pillow                       11.0.0
pip                          24.2
protobuf                     4.25.5
pycparser                    2.22
Pygments                     2.18.0
pyparsing                    3.2.0
python-dateutil              2.9.0.post0
requests                     2.32.3
rich                         13.9.4
scikeras                     0.11.0
scikit-learn                 1.3.0
scipy                        1.13.1
sentencepiece                0.2.0
setuptools                   75.1.0
six                          1.17.0
sounddevice                  0.5.1
tensorboard                  2.18.0
tensorboard-data-server      0.7.2
tensorflow                   2.18.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.37.1
termcolor                    2.5.0
threadpoolctl                3.5.0
tqdm                         4.67.1
typing_extensions            4.12.2
urllib3                      2.3.0
Werkzeug                     3.1.3
wheel                        0.44.0
wrapt                        1.17.0
zipp                         3.21.0

I also tried using pip install tensorflow[and-cuda] and then installing cuDNN instead of doing everything seperately. I am using python 3.9.21.

Try to come with a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You have too much code and it is very hard to inspect where the problem comes from. Users that have the same problem will have a hard time trying to find out if the solution suits them or not.
